# Jade , Could I pass the parameter into mixin like func(key="aaa")?

Tags: pug

I have variable number of parameters to pass in.

So could I pass the parameters like

```
+func(key="a",value="b",c="a")
```

I have tried but failed.

----To explain my problem more seriously----

In fact, I need mixin to build a large template. For example:

```
mixin template(a,b,c,d,e,f)
    div#1 !{a}
    div#2 !{b}
    div#3 !{c}
    if d
        div#4 !{d}
    if e
        div#5 !{e}
    div#6 !{f}

+template("a","b","c","","e","f")
```

if d don't exist, I still need to type an empty string, but I want not.

So I write in another form.

```
mixin template($)
    div#1 !{$.a}
    div#2 !{$.b}
    ....

+template({a="a",b="b",c="c",e="e",f="f"})
```

Then I can ignore the empty d. Could I omit the "$" as well?

Comment: Can you explain your question a little bit more? Do you want use multiple attributes rendered in a tag? Like <a key="a" value="b" c="a"></a> ?

Comment: To make it better understandable: can you please provide an example what you expect to be rendered for wich mixin call?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render something like

```
<a key="a" value="b" c="a"></a>
```

from an input like

```
+func(key="a",value="b",c="a")
```

use

```
mixin func()
  a&attributes(attributes)

+func(key="a",value="b",c="a")
```

**With dynamic tag**

```
mixin func()
  #{attributes.tag}&attributes(attributes.attr)

+func(tag="img", attr={key:"a",value:"b",c:"a"})
```

renders

```
<img key="a" value="b" c="a"></img>
```

**With dynamic tag and content**

```
mixin func()
  #{attributes.tag}&attributes(attributes.attr)=attributes.content

+func(tag="img", attr={key:"a",value:"b",c:"a"}, content="something")
```

renders

```
<img key="a" value="b" c="a">something</img>
```

---

In response to your comment: *In Javascript, I can pass the parameters in like func(a="b",c="d"),then use like func() { console.log(a) }. but in jade I think the alternative way is to pass an object in and use like func($) { console.log($.a) }*

Yes, in JS you can use `func($) { console.log($.a) }` (but you may only access exiting attributes of a. And you'll have to know about the attributes prior to write the code). Is JS just an example for the concept of passing an unknown amount of arguments? Then the above mixins will just do what you asked for (or better, what I understood what you asked for)

Or do you want to create a JS function from within a Jade-Template and define the arguments for the JS function in an Jade object? Then use something like:

```
mixin func()
  - var attr=attributes.attr
  - var k=[],v=[]
  - for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(attr).length; ++i) {
  -   k.push(Object.keys(attr)[i])
  -   v.push(attr[Object.keys(attr)[i]])
  - }

  script
    | function #{attributes.functionname}(!{k}) {
    |   // Whatever may be within the function
    |   !{attributes.content}
    | }
    | 
    | #{attributes.functionname}(!{v});

+func(functionname="myJSFunc", attr={key:"a",value:"b",c:"a",string:"'Paul'"},
 content="var q=1,r=2;\n    return q+r;")
```

Wich will render

```
<script>
  function myJSFunc(key,value,c,string) {
    // Whatever may be within the function
    var q=1,r=2;
    return q+r;
  }

  myJSFunc(a,b,a,'Paul');
</script>
```

Comment: In Javascript, I can pass the parameters in like `func(a="b",c="d")`,then use like `func() { console.log(a) }`. but in jade I think the alternative way is to pass an object in and use like `func($) { console.log($.a) }`

Comment: See extended question.